# mediawiki version 1.35.2 does not support Unicode

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Dears I have a problem with the mediawiki version 1.35.2. Its installed on CENTOS 7 with mysql server. The Startup work fine, but when an user create a new post, the system report a bellow error:

“It appears that your browser does not support Unicode. It is required to edit pages, so your edit was not saved.”

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I used chrome 90.0.4430.93  and Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.51.

Answer (score 0):

The edit page of MediaWiki sends a Unicode test-string to the server and
compares it with an internal constant. So two options: Either the HTTP request
actually contains a wrong string, or the PHP server has an issue.

Sometimes this happens if you have some proxy or process in-between that
mangles Unicode characters.

It's also possible that pages are being served with a wrong `content-type` header.
Check your php error log for "Headers already sent" error messages.
Check to ensure that the pages are really served with the header of
`Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: I not have proxy in environment. I have the enveroments below, in direfent hosts.
1) Virtualbox with local bridge network and virtualhost connected to 8080 port;
2) VirtualBox with host-only network and virtualhost connected to 8080 port.
I will look for error in logs, but not find the string “headers” there.
Are There other log file for php in httpd?

Comment: `Content-Type` is one type of header that you should be looking for. For PHP logging, see for example this [link](https://www.scalyr.com/blog/getting-started-quickly-with-php-logging).

Comment: I look for this, but not find too.
$cat /var/log/httpd/error_log |grep -i content
I am astonished. Is unusual the user input code on stable version.

Comment: Post online the file if you like, but check first that it's turned on and the error level.